# Template file "Error/error500.ctp" is missing. during Unit testing in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I have set up PHPUnit into my CakePHP application,

but when I try to run it I receive this error:

Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException: Template file "Error/error500.ctp" is missing.

I have tried several times with different settings of the phpunit.xml.dist page and nothing changes.

Here is the code:

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $this->get("/admin/users/login");
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Very simple method I am try to test within the tests/TestCase/Controller/Admin/UsersControllerTest.php

Comment: Please post the stacktrace that belongs to that error. Also, what does your `tests/bootstrap.php` file look like?

Comment: Here is tests/bootstrap.php `<?php 
/**
 * Test runner bootstrap.
 *
 * Add additional configuration/setup your application needs when running
 * unit tests in this file.
 */
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/bootstrap.php';

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure error500.ctp is present in template/Errro/ directory

Comment: Hi jags, yes the error500.ctp file is present in my template/Error/ folder and template/Admin/Error/ for the backend